# Connecting to redshift from powerBI using an private hosted zone alias created in Route53

Tags: amazon-route53, vpc-endpoint, amazon-redshift-serverless

I have a redshift serverless workgroup (not public) that I can connect to from powerBI using the AWS generated redshift workgroup URL. However I want to provide a easy to remember URL to everyone to connect to the workgroup. We do have a private hosted zone on route 53 in the same AWS account so I create a A record alias pointing to the vpc endpoint of the redshift workgroup. The alias works when SSL encryption is turned off on PowerBI for the connection however it doesnt work when I try it with encrypted connection. The error I get is

```
Details: "ODBC: ERROR [08S01] [Microsoft][Amazon Redshift] (10) Error occurred while trying to connect: [SQLState 08S01] server certificate for "12345678xx.us-east-1.redshift-serverless.amazonaws.com" (and 1 other name) does not match host name "redshift.example.net"
```

I understand what this is causing, simply, the hostname I type in my connection string, doesnt match what the sever certificate responding to it and therefore they cant encrypt the connection.

What else could I do to encrypt the connection and have the easy to remember URL?